# Как перенести данные из одной книги в другую excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Всем привет, как при  помощи эксель VBA осуществить перенос таблицы из одной книги в другую, никакие фильтры не нужны есть таблица A1-Z1 и её нужно переместить при помощи VBA в другую книгу на такое же место A2-Z2

Comment: *её нужно переместить при помощи VBA в другую книгу на такое же место A1-Z1* На листе назначения что-то ещё - есть? или до перемещения лист нов и чист?

Comment: До перемещения лист полностью чистый, только наверху строка A покрашена в серый цвет и на неё нельзя залезать

Comment: *лист полностью чистый, только наверху строка* Или чист, или нет. А "чист, вот только .." - это глупость. Нельзя быть немножко беременной.. *строка A покрашена в серый цвет и на неё нельзя залезать* с учётом необходимости копирования *на такое же место A1-Z1* задача не решается даже теоретически.

Comment: Понял, поправил описание

Comment: Переместить - как? В первой книге вырезать диапазон и сместить ячейки вверх-влево? Очистить диапазон?

Comment: Из первой книги из диапозона A1-Z1 скопировать данные
Переместить их в другую книгу на место A2-Z2
Данные в исходной книге должны быть сохранены

Comment: Copy на исходном листе, PasteSpecial на листе назначения. При необходимости копирования и разметки (ширина столбцов, например) придётся PasteSpecial выполнить дважды.

Comment: Так не переместить, а создать копию (копировать)! Запишите действия макрорекодером. Посмотрите, что получится. И после этого с вопросами...